# SQL Order By On two columns but same prority

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stuck on this simple select and don't know what to do.
I Have this:

```
   ID | Group
   ===========
    1 | NULL
    2 | 100
    3 | 100
    4 | 100
    5 | 200
    6 | 200
    7 | 100
    8 | NULL
```

and want this:

```
   ID | Group
   ===========
    1 | NULL
    2 | 100
    3 | 100
    4 | 100
    7 | 100
    5 | 200
    6 | 200
    8 | NULL
```

all group members keep together, but others order by ID.
I can not write this script because of that NULL records. NULL means that there is not any group for this record.

Comment: Why there is a NULL at top and another at bottom?

Comment: these are random records, nulls can be placed in any other rows

Comment: So you want the `order by` clause to ignore the `null` records when sorting by group?

Comment: yes, exactly. you know what I want!

Comment: `SELECT ID, Group FROM your_table ORDER BY Group;`

Comment: Just curious, why don't you want the ones without a group to appear together also?  And what if you had a row with ID 9 and group 100, where should that appear in the list relative to id 8?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat because the insert order is important in my app, but keeping group members together is important too. null means no group, or better I say single record group, or group with one record. there is not record named NULL

Comment: @ArashGhasemiRad I see, but how does that affect when they should appear in the order when you're ordering by group? Should a value with id 8 appear before id 9 if 8 is a single member group (null) and 9 has group 100?  I would think though that it would be best to assign a group id to them since you say they are "in a single member group".  What is the problem with ordering by `group` so that all the null group rows appear first?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat if there is any other record with group 100 before id 8, then id 9 must be before id 8 (in my example, id 9 must be before 8). else id 9 must be after id 8. it is important to save insert order, so we cannot order by group. but it is more important that group members keep together. I can assign a float number like 100.1 to null groups, but it is harder than true answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you want to order your rows by the minimum ID of their group - or their own ID in case they belong to no group.Then you want to order by ID. That is:

```
order by min(id) over (partition by case when grp is null then id else grp end), id
```

If IDs and groups can overlap (i.e. the same number can be used for an ID and for a group, e.g. add a record for ID 9 / group 1 to your sample data) you should change the partition clause to something like

```
order by min(id) over (partition by case when grp is null 
                                    then 'ID' + cast(id as varchar)
                                    else 'GRP' + cast(grp as varchar) end),
         id;
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GPHBW5600

Comment: I just noticed that my solution had a glitch, though. In your sample IDs are one digit and groups are three digits, but in your real data there may be overlapping values. So the partition clause should account for this. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: When I add data after the null it does not seem to work correctly but OP gave it the check mark.

Comment: @paparazzo: Data after the null? You can add something to the rextester demo, save it (and thus get a new link), and tell me what you think is not working. The query should work for all cases, so I suppose you may be merely misunderstanding the task.

Comment: If OP says it works correctly then fine.  Not what I thought the OP was describing.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner See data in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about data after a null?  In a comment you said don't sort the null.

```
declare @T table (ID int primary key, grp int);
insert into @T values
       (1, NULL)
     , (3, 100)
     , (5, 200)
     , (6, 200)
     , (7, 100)
     , (8, NULL)
     , (9, 200)
     , (10, 100)
     , (11, NULL)
     , (12, 150);
select ttt.* 
  from (  select tt.* 
               , sum(ff) over (order by tt.ID) as sGrp
          from ( select t.*
                      , iif(grp is null or lag(grp) over (order by id) is null, 1, 0) as ff 
                   from @T t
               ) tt
       ) ttt
order by ttt.sGrp, ttt.grp, ttt.id

ID          grp         ff          sGrp
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           NULL        1           1
3           100         1           2
7           100         0           2
5           200         0           2
6           200         0           2
8           NULL        1           3
10          100         0           4
9           200         1           4
11          NULL        1           5
12          150         1           6
```

Comment: NULL simply means it doesn't belong to a (bigger) group, but builds a group on its own so to say. (Just build imaginary groups in your mind to see them: ID 1 one belongs to group 'ID1', ID 8 belongs to group 'ID8'.) The groups shall be together in the results, so all grp 100 should be together for instance, which isn't the case in your example. Then the groups shall be ordered according to their IDs. You see from the example that the OP uses the minimum ID per group, so group 100 comes before group 200, because its minimum ID 2 is less then group 200's minimum ID 5.

Comment: As groups are to be shown adjacent, ID 7 comes before ID 5, because it belongs to group 100, which is shown before group 200. At last IDs shall be sorted inside each group, so ID 2 comes before ID 3, ID 3 comes before ID 4 and ID 4 comes before ID 7.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I don't have question here.  I understood the OP differently and there is not enough data to validate.

Comment: thank you for your response, but I said don't sort null records, but sort not null records, so null records may lose their position if other records reorder. All group members must be kept together and this may change null records position. @ThorstenKettner knows what I said, and his new edit is correct (I double checked my real data and you were right, on group and ID overlap, prev answer was incorrect)

Comment: @ArashGhasemiRad You question is not clear on the matter and if you would have included a null in the middle in the sample I would have at least know I don't understand the question.

Comment: @paparazzo excuse me for bad description. you are right, this is my mistake.